# AWS Elasticbeanstalk Upgrade Issue Caused by lovell/sharp module

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, sharp

I'm trying to upgrade a live node application that resides in AWS Elastcibeanstalk from v8.12.0 to v10.13.0
and the only issue that I see is caused by sharp complaining about being built with a different version.

Here's the error:

Error: The module '/var/app/current/node_modules/sharp/build/Release/sharp.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using npm rebuild or npm install).

I can't upgrade our prod aws elb instances because of this issue.

Not sure what to do at this point..

Comment: Curious if you found a solution here?  I am seeing similar

Comment: @AnthonyWebb No, I haven't. I still haven't upgraded the elb node version because of this.